# Is discord bot only run when I run the bot.py file?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a simple discord bot : sending message with python

..here ! I got a question about Discord bot that I made.

Is Discord bot only work when I am running the bot.py file??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's logical. If you don't run the file, the bot won't be "online"

Comment: No worries, remember to accept it if it helped